# How to Display Components using ngFor in angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular6

I am using Angular 6. In my case, I have a list of tabs, which are conditional on several user actions. Now, all the tabs are including components as a part of content. At present, I have to manually add tab's name and check for condition which is not efficient. Is it possible to use *ngFor to display components?
Here is example of my current scenario:

```
<app-tab1 *ngIf='showTabsArray == 1'></app-tab1>
<app-tab2 *ngIf='showTabsArray == 2'></app-tab2>
```

Comment: Can you please share little more code? describe what you want to achieve with `*ngFor`. Example: need to iterate through `tabsArray` (list of tabs), however to display only if (some condition). It'll be easier if little additional context is shared in the question.

Comment: what happened when you tried to create a component with *ngFor, any error ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ngFor` has an option to generate a counter, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of array; let i = index">
```

Then, put your component class names into an array. Use `ngComponentOutlet` to display them, like this:

```
<div *ngFor="let componentClass of componentClassArray; let i = index">

  // Only one structural directive is allowed per tag, hence we wrap the following
  // ng-container with ngComponentOutlet property in one more conditional div

  <div *ngIf="showTabsArray == i">
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="componentClass" ></ng-container>
  </div>

</div>
```

Other than getting an index value from `ngFor` using `let i = index`, you can get a few more interesting values from it.

```
... let i = index // iteration number / integer
... let c = count // total number of items in object / integer
... let e = even  // true or false / boolean
... let o = odd   // true or false / boolean
... let f = first // true or false / boolean
... let l = last  // true or false / boolean
```